# regex match not if in the same line

Tags: python, regex

I have created a regex that match my custom html tag.
For example:

```
<var-input id="" kind="{&quot;id&quot;:2,&quot;art&quot;:&quot;TEXT&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Textfeld&quot;,&quot;default&quot;:null}" choices="1,2,3,four" value="radio not text"></var-input>
```

The html-tag always have the form `<var-input id="" kind="" choices="" value=""></var-input>`

And these are the restrictions:

- `id` is an uuid4 string or empty
- `kind` is a JSON stringify object
- `choices` is an array (comma separated) or empty
- `value` is a string or empty

This is my regex now:

```
<var-input id=\"([0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12})?\" kind=\"({.*})\" choices=\"([a-zA-Z0-9_,\s]*)\" value=\"([a-zA-Z0-9_,\s]*)\"></var-input>
```

It works good for one match like the above example. But is there more than one `<var-input ...></var-input>` in one line, the regex not work correct.
Why?

[Here is an example](https://regex101.com/r/XA1p5x/6)

Comment: did use use the correct flags and python regex functions for multiple matches eg [findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)

Comment: Look at my example on regex101.com. What flags do you mean?

Comment: Apart from the usual reservation to use regex for xml: what routine uses the regular expression? `find()` or `match()`?

Comment: At the moment i try it with `re.findall()` but if you think another function is better than i can use another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make `{.*}` not greedy: `{.*?}`.

[Updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/XA1p5x/7)